# HTML5 block positioning

Tags: html

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEFNd.png

I'm new to HTML5 so my code is likely to be messy, I'm trying to lay out block elements as shown above, but because I've chosen the body to float left it ends up below the slideshow. Here's how I've coded it:

```
#container {
    height: 800px;
    width: 985px;
    position:relative;
}


    <article> 
    <span class="titlespacer">title text here</span></p>

  <ul>
    <li class="bodyspacer">Bullet</li>
    <span class="bodyspacer"><br>
      </span>
    <li class="bodyspacer">Bullet</li>
    <span class="bodyspacer"><br>
      </span>
    <li class="bodyspacer">Bullet</li>
    <span class="bodyspacer"><br>
      </span>
    <li class="bodyspacer">Bullet</li>
    <span class="bodyspacer"><br>
      </span>
    <li class="bodyspacer">Bullet</li>
</ul>
<aside>
    <div id="slideshow">
    <img src="images/polaroid1.jpg" width="320" height="332" class="polaroid">
    <img src="images/polaroid2.jpg" width="320" height="332" class="polaroid">
    <img src="images/polaroid3.jpg" width="320" height="332" class="polaroid">
  </div>
    </aside>
</article>
```

CSS

```
    #slideshow {
        height:  332px;
        width:   320px;
        float: none;
        clear:both;
    } 

.bodyspacer {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'droid sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 460px;
    padding-right: 70px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    list-style-image: url(../fishing/images/rod.png);
    clear: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.titlespacer {
    font-family: 'Arvo', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 435px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #1B378B;
    margin-right: 10px;
    height: 35px;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border: 3px double #FFF;
    margin-left: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Try applying `overflow: hidden` to the parent container of `body`.

Comment: Why so many images with the same ID? That could mess up JavaScript code.

Comment: Changed the ID to a class, thanks. It was originally one picture but when I added more I must have copied the ID without noticing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll need the following:

your css

```
#container {
width:960px;
position:relative;
}
header{
float:left;
}
article{
width:600px;
float:left;
}
aside{
width:360px;
float:left;
}
.clear{
clear:both;
}
```

your html5

```
<div id="container">
<header>your header</header>
<article>
    <section>your content</section>
</article>
<aside>
    <div id="slideshow">
        <ul>
        <li><img src="..."></li>
        <li><img src="..."></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</aside>
<div class="clear"></div>
<footer>your footer</footer>
</div>
```

i hope it helped you!

Comment: The slideshow is still appearing underneath the body, I'll amended my original post with the updated code.

Comment: I've updated my code - I realize it's messy but I appreciate your help!